# Emacs magit command that shows names of modified files in a branch

Tags: git, emacs, magit

While on a branch, I'm looking to run effectively this command:

```sh
git diff --name-only master...
```

using magit.  What is the appropriate keystroke to see the names of files that have been modified on a branch like the above?

Comment: Just run `M-x magit-status` and you will see all Unstaged Changes and Staged Changes (i.e. all modified files)?

Comment: I'm looking not only for staged and unstaged changes, but all files that have been modified in the branch, even already committed and pushed---so they no longer appear in staged and unstaged.  The same result as the command above.

Comment: As far as I know, magit don't have a function and key bind for that. You can write a functions and bind to the keystroke you like.

Comment: Makes sense---this is basically the github pull request view for the branch and I find it super useful to navigate my work.

Comment: Maybe ask on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a `magit` command to do this.